# Como forçar usar o método com float em vez do método com o double?

Tags: c#

Como forçar usar o método com float em vez do método double?

```
public static void Dividir(double dividendo, double divisor)
{
    //https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/579137/Division-By-Zero-Doesnt-Always-Raise-An-Exception
    if (divisor == 0)
        throw new DivideByZeroException();
}

public static void Dividir(float dividendo, float divisor)
{
    var resultado = dividendo / divisor;
}
```

Pertendo chamar o método com os argumentos em float como faço?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa chamar o método passando *floats* por parâmetro, ex:

```
float num1 = 1.1;
float num2 = 2.2;
Dividir(num1, num2);
```

Caso já tenha os números e não seja *float*, basta dar um *cast*:

```
int num1 = 1.1;
int num2 = 2.2;
Dividir((float)num1, (float)num2);
```

Comment: Ainda passei de outra forma que descobri que é  Dividir(10.0f, 10.3f);

Comment: Se passar apenas assim Dividir(10.0, 10.0); cai no double